# How to deploy a Gmail add-on until G Suite add-ons are fully rolled out

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, gsuite-addons

I understand that [G Suite Add-ons won't be fully available until February 2020](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview).

Before they released G Suite Add-ons we could deploy unpublished Gmail Add-ons to test them by using the adding the deployment ID in Gmail settings after enabling developer add-ons.

This does not seem to be working anymore. When I try to test unpublished Gmail add-ons I get the error "This developer add-on is restricted by policies within your organization." I was able to test these add-ons before.

I would assume that we could still test Gmail add-ons until G Suite add-ons are fully available.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have a G-Suite Business account and I have several Gmail Addons working that I did for myself.

Comment: When did you last try to test a deployment? Does it let you do it right now? I could do it before -- only now I can't.

Comment: I used deploy from Manifest

Comment: Same. It’s not working anymore. I deploy from manifest, get deployment ID, then add it in Gmail. It adds but gives that error I pasted in the questions.

Comment: Not for me. I just added one and it works okay.

Comment: Doh! I wonder why mine won’t. :/

Comment: Try contacting your admin. There is likely some new or updated setting they have to enable that will allow the add-on to be used within your organization.

Comment: Hello @IMTheNachoMan, did you make any changes to your add-on recently? More precisely to the scopes and/or authorization settings?

Comment: @ale13 no. In fact I am getting this error when creating a new one — one of the starter samples.

Comment: Do you still get the error after doing these steps: `1.` You should enable users to be able to install Add-ons; `2.` Enable the APIs that Apps Script will use;
`3.` Whitelist Apps Script projects. ? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 Yes. I was able do this a few weeks ago. I didn’t change anything. It stopped working when they release the new features.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan, do you still get the same error? Have you checked/updated your settings? Cheers!

Comment: No. The add-ons work now. I didn't do or change anything. It started working again all of a sudden. Very strange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, 2020-01-31, I am no longer getting the error. I did not do or change anything. I assume Google made a change to fix the issue.